# Tensorflow-gpu only trains custom object detection models using version 1.14

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am ecstatic that I have found a setup where I can train and test my custom object detection models but I am confused why the latest tensorflow-gpu version doesn't work on my PC when another setup works on my laptop:

#### The Setup I am using(PC):

- OS: Windows 10
- Python: 3.6.4
- TensorFlow: 1.14.0(gpu)
- CUDA: 10
- cudnn: 9.0?(can't remember)
- repo + location: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection

#### The Setup I am using(laptop):

- OS: OSX
- Python: 3.7.5
- TensorFlow: 2.1.0-rc0(standard)
- repo + location: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection

how(when?) can I train custom models using tensorflow-gpu v2.0.0 on my PC?

thx

Answer (score 1):

If you need to run tensorflow-gpu on Windows, [Microsoft Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) is a pre-requisite. This requirement is also mentioned [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html). You can download the community version of Visual Studio 2019 [here](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/).

Though this requirement is not directly mentioned in [tensorflow-gpu installation docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu), it is a part of [CUDA installation guide for Windows](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/). Also you need to ensure you have a NVIDIA GPU card with CUDA Compute Capability **3.5 or higher**. You can check if your GPU meets the Compute Capability requirement [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus).

Here are a few resources to help with tf-gpu installation:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-on-windows-10-60693e46e781
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZFn0dvPZUQ